# Contact numbers saved as 'other' on outlook will not sync with my Nokia Lumia 900

Tags: sync, contacts, outlook

Contact numbers saved as 'other' on outlook will not sync with my Nokia Lumia 900.
I have 2000+ contacts generated over 10+ years and saved via various mobile devices over the years. These have been saved as 'other' on Outlook and whilst the contact name is syncing the number filed on the phone remains blank.
Is there a way to reclassify the number on Outlook to enable synchronising?

Comment: Outlook and Exchange [have long standing issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2692134) (and limits) to contacts

Answer (score 1):

I'd think the best option would be to move the Phone number out of other.  Open powershell and run the following code

```
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application
$contacts = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(10)
$contacts.Items | % { if($_.MobileTelephoneNumber -eq "") { $_.MobileTelephoneNumber = $_.OtherTelephoneNumber; $_.OtherTelephoneNumber = ""; $_.save() } }
```

Source: http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/outlook-contacts-move-all-numbers-from-other-phone-to-mobile-phone-field/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have Outlook on my computer but I think I have an idea, although a little tedious.

- Using Outlook 2010 -

  1. Export your contacts twice into a CSV from outlook: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/export-contacts-HA101870639.aspx.
  2. Next, save one file as a back up and open the other with Excel.
  3. In this CSV there should be "Other Phone" Heading.
  4. Copy & Paste this entire column to 'Mobile Phone' column or another accepted phone type (go into your 'people' on your 920, click + to add a new contact and click + phone and click the phone number type box). DONT MISS ANY NUMBERS or you will jumble your contacts and their phone numbers.
  5. Now, you must save the .CSV and import it: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/outlook-help/import-contacts-HA101870645.aspx you will have to click: "Replace items with duplicates imported".

Once that is done you should be able to sync properly with your phone :) best of luck!

Comment: Thanks starkey01 but no joy! I exported the file into excel but a number of issues occurred, 1. all my phone numbers exported to excel without the 0 at the front, 1. any numbers that were saved in my contacts as +44 saved as a formula and 3. when I imported back to outlook I've ended up with 3 entries per contact. I have had to reset outlook from last night's back up and will seek further assistance. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

There is no way or work around this. Outlook.com has limitations and will not correctly sync/import all fields from MS Outlook CSV. The only way would be to manually edit entries in Outlook.com. whatever is in Outlook.com, that will be the same when you sync your WP8.